# Installing python-pcl on Debian 10 : libpcl_keypoints import error

Tags: python, debian, importerror, point-cloud-library, nosuchfileexception

I am trying to install python-pcl library (see https://github.com/Sirokujira/python-pcl/tree/rc_patches4)

At first I installed pcl lib using :
`sudo apt install libpcl-dev -y`
And then
`python3.6 -m pip install python-pcl`
(I have to install it on a specific version of python)

Then I ran
`python3.6`
and try to import python-pcl library
`import pcl`

But I get this error message :
`ImportError: libpcl_keypoints.so.1.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

If anyone had the same issue, I am very very interested in a solution